# Использование readline_info()

Tags: php, консоль

Ребятки, кто плотно работал с readline выручайте. Задача реализовать контекстный автокомплит. То есть если я ввожу numbers<пробел> и нажимаю таб,то мой контекст, это все что до последнего пробела, и все это может помочь дать конкретный контекстный комплит, в случае контекста numbers я например верну массив чисел.

Если я правильно понял документацию текущий контекст я могу получить через readline_info('line_buffer')(далее LB), но по факту LB возвращает предыдущую введенную комманду, то есть я что то напечатал, нажал ентер и вот мой ввод попадет в LB только при следующем считывании

Код для тестов

```
readline_completion_function(function($input) {
    // вот здесь ожидается увидеть весь текущий ввод,
    // а не предыдущую введеную комманду
    var_dump(readline_info('line_buffer'));

    return ['help', 'quit'];
});

while(true) {
    readline('cmd: ');
}
```